# Duplicate a class instance

Tags: vb.net

Soo, I have a combo box who have as datasource a list of custom object (the "Person" class). I have mapped the Person.Name to be the DisplayMember, and the object is the value selected.

when someone select a "Bob" person and press on ChoosePerson, I want to take this person, duplicate it, and use the duplicata to do stuff.

Heres the code to explain it :

```
 Private Sub ChoosePerson_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChoosePerson.Click
    Dim p As Person= CType(cbPerson.SelectedValue, Person)
    MyChosenList.Add(ChoseAPerson(m))
    cbPerson.SelectedIndex() = 0
End Sub

Private function ChoseAPerson(byval p as Person) as Person
   Dim newPerson as Person = p 
   newPerson.name = "ANewPerson_"  & p.Name
   Return newPerson
End function
```

Now, if I go back to my combo box cbPerson, the person I selected earlier (bob) will have its name replace for "ANewPerson_bob"

how can I make sure that the "bob" person I add to myChosenList is a different instance of Person class ?

EDIT

I add to scout a little on google to find the right way to do a clone of my object as @dotNET suggested it

```
Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
    Return DirectCast(MemberwiseClone(), Person)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to solve this problem is to implement `IClonable` and then `Clone()` method to create a copy of your object. Then in your code, write this:

```
Dim p As Person= CType(cbPerson.SelectedValue, Person).Clone()
```

The basic problem is that Persons is a *class*, and is therefore copied by reference and not by value. Creating a new reference still points to the same physical object.

Comment: your officially my new best friend if this works, I'll try it right away !

Comment: Great, this works well and a shallow clone is all I need atm. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this:

```
Dim newPerson as Person = p
```

You need to write a copy constructor for `Person`, and do this:

```
Dim newPerson as New Person(p)
```

Comment: urk ... the person class is ... huge ... that will be a pain to write down ... but if I have no other choice I guess